# what does data-cfapps-unplaceable mean?

Tags: cloudflare-apps

With some websites the design of the application is corrupted and the behavior is unexpected. 
I noticed that when the happens all the tags are marked with data-cfapps-unplaceable.
BTW, I am appending directly to the body tag so the user does not have to pick a location
Here is an example:

```html
<div class="popup" data-cfapps-unplaceable=""><div class="exit_popup box" data-cfapps-unplaceable="">
```

I suspect this is the reason the elements are not showing correctly. Any idea what is the cause and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

since the site is corrupt or having unexpected behavior, we use this tag to make sure that we don’t add elements which could farther break the site.
Rest of convo here: https://community.cloudflare.com/t/what-does-data-cfapps-unplaceable-mean/25844